# rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed when installing SQL Developer 18

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, redhat

I cant install sql developer on my RHEL 5.6 32-bit

Whenever I run rpm -Uvh sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-1.noarch.rpm , I keep getting this errors saying :

error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-1.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-1.noarch

Previously I already installed the jdk1.8-1.8.0_171-fcs.i586 because that's a requirement. 
I also have read from some sources, saying that it has something to do with its rpm version compatibility. Thus, so far I've tried installing sql develover 4 instead of 18 with the same result

I'm really new to this, what should I do to be able to install sql developer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do what the error messages are telling you, get rpmlib FileDigests and PayloadlsXz. Or, skip all that and just download the Zip and have a go

Comment: I tried to search for those rpm, but didn't find any so far. So, I tried installing sqldeveloper-3.2.20.09.87-1.noarch.rpm instead and it worked. But thanks for your suggestion, i'll try searching for the rpm again

Answer (score 1):

The RPM version on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 does not support XZ compression for the file contents stored in RPM packages.  It was added in [RPM 4.7](http://rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.7.0), but Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 only has RPM 4.4.  Support for XZ-compressed sources and patches in rpmbuild was backported, but not support for payload compression.

For some reason, RPM using XZ payload compression (and SHA-256 file digests) express this as an artificial dependency with an incorrect version constraint (`<= 4.6.0-1`), so even though your RPM version is less than that and thus matches the dependency, it is still not sufficient.  It's just a very bad error message.

You will either have to unpack the RPM on a different system and copy it over (using `rpm2cpio` and `cpio`), or get an RPM built for use on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 from Oracle.